# jquery on form calculation max values without submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, max, limit

how can i do dynamic form calculation without submit?  submitting is about php server. I need to calculate this form with limiting max values. Example result value can't be above buy value. when above must give error  submit button disabled.
I can't find any solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#storage","#result","#account").on(keyup, change(function(){
      var abc = $("#abc").val();
     var price = $("#price").val();
    var storage = $("#capacity").val() - $("#abc").val();
    $("#storage").val(storage);
     var result = $("#price").val() * $("#abc").val();
 $("#result").val(result);
  var account = buy - result;
   $("#account").val(account);
});
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="" >
 <input id="buy" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="buy" value="5000000" />
    <input type="hidden" id="capacity"  class="form-control" name="capacity"  value="1000000" />
Storage : <input id="storage" type="text" class="form-control" name="storage" min="0" max="1000000" value=""/><br>
Abc: <input id="abc" type="text" class="form-control" name="abc" min="0" max="1000000" value="" /> <br>
Price: <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" value="15" /> <br>
Result: <input id="result" type="text" class="form-control" name="result" value=""/> <br>
Account: <input id="account" type="text" class="form-control" name="account" max="5000000" value="" /> <br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">  
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an input / keyup event listener. For example (Vanilla JS):

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
  // Do your stuff here
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
```

Or with jQuery:

```js
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
  console.log($("#myInput").val());
  // Do your stuff here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" />
```

Although this is heplful, JavaScript (besides Node) is client-side and can be easily overriden, so make sure you evaluate the input in the backend too.